# Update dropdown attribute value Programtically for single product

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, event-observer, dropdown-attribute

Onclick **Add to cart** button we are trying to update the Attribute value from "NO" to "YES".

[ **attribute code** : `cart_status` (Yes/No dropdown) Attribute ]

I tried below code, its changing attribute values for all products, but i need to change value only for that particular product that i added to cart.

```
<?php

foreach ($collections as $key => $product) 
{
    echo $product->getName().' <br><br>';           
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());             
?>

<form action="<?php 

echo  Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product);

// update cart_status

    echo "\n".'updating '.$_product->getSku()."...\n";
    $_product->setData('cart_status', 1)->getResource()->saveAttribute($_product, 'cart_status');
    $_product->save(); 

// update cart_status end

?>" method="post">  
<div>

<button>Add to cart</button>

</div>
</form>
```

**Update**

After following [Dhiren Vasoya's Solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178194/update-dropdown-attribute-value-programtically-for-single-product/178482#178482) , once i click on `Add to cart`, In **1)Frontend** its changing Attribute value [From **"NO" to "YES"** , but once i refresh page, again it showing old value [ **NO** ] , But in **2)In Backend, updated Values are not showing for "Default Values**" , but showing for "**Stores**"

**Default values** :

[image]

**Stores** :

[image]

**config** :

```
<checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
                <example_add_to_cart_after>
                  <class>Amasty_Example_Model_Observer</class>
                  <method>AddToCartAfter</method>
                </example_add_to_cart_after>
            </observers>
</checkout_cart_product_add_after>
```

app/code/local/Amasty/Example/Model/Observer.php

```
class Amasty_Example_Model_Observer 
{
    public function AddToCartAfter($observer)
    {

         $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();         
         $product->setCartStatus(1);
         $product->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: i am following this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999439/updating-magento-attribute-programatically , same code i am using......

Comment: The link that you provide above is sample code to do a batch save of products (aka an admin product save/bulk update). It seems as if you are trying to update the product attribute of a quote item. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @RenonStewart I am trying to update a single product attribute value from frontend. but its updating for all products.....

Comment: Have you something in your error logs?

Comment: @sv3n log error 1 : `Recoverable Error: Argument 3 passed to Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract::_canUpdateAttribute() must be of the type array, null given, called in /app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 1225 and defined  in /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Abstract.php on line 543`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add observer throught you extension config.xml.

**app/code/CODEPOOL/Vendor/Extension/etc/config.xml**

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
                <extension_add_to_cart_after>
                    <class>YOUR_OBSERVER_CLASS</class>
                    <method>AddToCartAfter</method>
                </extension_add_to_cart_after>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

Now you have to code in yorr observer.php file like this :

**app/code/CODEPOOL/Vendor/Extension/Model/Observer.php**

```
class Vendor_Extension_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Observer
{
    public function AddToCartAfter($observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();         
        $product->setCartStatus(1);
        $product->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: onclick `add to cart` button, attribute values are updating now, but once i refresh page, again it show old values only.....

Comment: can you clear cache and indexing.

Comment: done reindexing & cleared cache, still same issue.....

Answer (score 0):

1. override your checkout controller there in `addAction` after add to cart code use your code.
2. OR create an event observer `checkout_cart_product_add_after` there you can get the particular product.

For the above process, if you not familiar do google you'll get those information.

Comment: thanks for reply, is there any easy way to solve this other than those 2 you mentioned in answer..... ? because once i click `add to cart` attribute value is already changing  for all products , i need to change the value only for that particular product...... if there is no other easy solution, i will surely follow yours, please let me know about this.....

Comment: Try to pass the **product ID** onclick the Add to cart event and filter with that ID into your collection.

Answer (score 0):

you want to update particular product attribute value which one is getting added to cart. So it will better if you use observer for add to cart. Using that you can update attribute value for the specific product that you are adding to cart.

Comment: provide detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using event `checkout_cart_product_add_after` and then utilise the code mentioned [here](http://www.magentoformat.com/magento-update-dropdown-product-attribute-value/)

Answer (score 0):

For your error message ... please try this code in your observer method:

```
$product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
    array($product->getId()),
    array('cart_status' => 1),
    $storeId
);
```

**Note:** set `$storeId` to `0` if you want to save it as default value or use `Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()` for store view specific value.

Comment: Thanks, those error messages in log file gone now after updating your code, but the original issue is still there......

Comment: What do you mean? Value is set for all products OR value is not set to "Default Value"?

Comment: i set `$storeId=0` but still onclick `add to cart` button , attribute value is updating only for `stores` [ not for default values] also once we refresh the page in frontend, it show old values only......

Comment: Can you please double-check your code. And remove the "update code" from your original answer. I've tested it and works as intended?!?

Comment: Found the issue, when i tried with other dropdown attribute, it worked fine.... but not for this attribute : `cart_status`......

Comment: It should also work with `cart_status` ;) Feel free to accept the answer if it works for you :)

Comment: Have you other code that modifies `cart_status` attribute?

Comment: yes we have an option from doing from mobile app side also [ android] , but right now they are not working on it.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60305/discussion-between-sv3n-and-vickey-colors).

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom module

app/code/local/MagePal/UpdateProductOnAddToCart/etc/config.xml

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
                <magepal_updateproductonaddtocart_add_to_cart_after>
                    <class>MagePal_UpdateProductOnAddToCart_Observer</class>
                    <method>AddToCartAfter</method>
                </magepal_updateproductonaddtocart_add_to_cart_after>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

Observer

app/code/local/MagePal/UpdateProductOnAddToCart/Model/Observer.php

```
class MagePal_UpdateProductOnAddToCart_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Observer
{
    public function AddToCartAfter($observer)
    {
        // Set store id to admin
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
        $product_id = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getId();
        $store_id = 0;

        $action = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_product_action');
        $action->updateAttributes(array($product_id), array(
            'cart_status' => 1
        ), $store_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated your code, once we click on `add to cart` , `cart_status` attribute value is changing to `yes` and once i refresh page, again its displaying `No` , but  its working fine for other attributes , is there any idea what may be wrong for that particular attribute `cart_status` [scope : global ]

Comment: When you "refresh" what page (admin or cart page)?

Comment: i refresh in My account page as we displaying products there...

Comment: Global scope should be store id = 0, which you should not be able to save to from the frontend unless you are using  Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

Comment: What are you showing in "My account page" products or cart item?

Comment: in my account page, we are displaying products and provided an option to add those products to cart : http://prntscr.com/fitawe

Comment: Since you stated "but its working fine for other attributes", does it work correctly if you change it in the admin. Correctly if I'm wrong but the first time someone adds that item to cart it will set to "yes" forever in the admin?

Comment: yes if we change in admin manualy, than it will work..... when i add product to cart , the page refresh and display `yes` in frontend.... once i check in backend, it show `No` only..... it will set to "yes" forever only when we change manually.....

Comment: Does it still display "yes" if you refresh frontend?

Comment: once i refresh , it show old value [ that is `No`]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60306/discussion-between-renon-stewart-and-vickey-colors).